# Anyone building or built - an API Call into Zoom to Add A Meeting Registrant

Tags: civievent, zoom

I have CIVI Events installed on my site and I am looking to integrate with Zoom /Meetings. With an Event Registration i want to take the Participant record. Post the information to Zoom API call  Meetings Registrants - then write the response back into the Civi Events Calendar object for that user, the unique registration URL. Is there a civiextension for this, or anyone available to help us with this piece of work?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom

We have forked the original extension, I would use ours as we have fixes/changes to make it configurable and the original developer hasn't yet accepted them.

At the moment it works with webinars but we can adapt it to work with meetings too.

Let us know if you need anything else or you can raise issues on the repo for anything you need.

Thanks

Comment: Nice one Parvez!

Comment: Thank you Parvez.- I will send the details for the adaption to work with Meetings...

Comment: I have added a bunch of possible documentation to https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/ncn-civi-zoom/issues/9

Comment: Needs the 'webminar' typo fixing in the code :-)

Comment: And change Custom Field to 'Custom Field for Webinar' since it needs to make sense now we also have Custom Field for Meeting

Comment: Thats great, thanks Pere - note we've also extended it to allow multiple zoom accounts to be used under a civicrm install. Our use case was an organisation who has multiple branches, each of whom run their own zoom accounts to make it easier to schedule meetings etc.